# How to mock a list in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-mock

For example, I have some code which tries to access a list:

```
def some_code():
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

I need to mock `sys.argv[0]`. So I add `@patch.object` to my test:

```
import os
import sys

THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
@mock.patch.object(sys, 'argv', mock.Mock(return_value=[THIS_DIR]))
def test_mytest():
    some_code()
```

But this doesn't work. Pytest raises error:

```
>     script_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
E     TypeError: 'Mock' object does not support indexing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use a `Mock` object to replace a list, just replace `sys.argv` with a different list. You can still use `mock.patch` to manage the replacing and undoing however:

```
@mock.patch.object(sys, 'argv', [THIS_DIR])
```

Do note that you probably want to pass in a filename, not the directory (unless your test directory is nested under the actual directory you wanted to be used).

Your mock configuration replaced `sys.argv` with a callable object, so only `sys.argv()` would have produced your `[THIS_DIR]` list.

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> sys.argv
['']
>>> with mock.patch.object(sys, 'argv', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
...     sys.argv
...
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> sys.argv
['']
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, "@mock.patch.object(sys, 'argv', [THIS_DIR])" version works!